# adding the sum of tables into one of the tables with a new date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, examples below

**tblOrders**

```
ID   Quantity
ABC  5    
XYZ  25
MNO  -50
WWL  -35
```

**tblHoldings**

```
Date   ID   Quantity
2-Jan  ABC  100    
2-Jan  PPP  12
2-Jan  MNO  200
2-Jan  WWL  35
```

What I need to do is take the current holdings from tblHoldings and add the data from the tblOrders & insert the results into the tblHoldings with a new date. So the result should look like below. Please note that WWL has a zero quantity so there should be new record for WWL for the new date.

**tblHoldings**

```
Date   ID   Quantity
2-Jan  ABC  100    
2-Jan  PPP  12
2-Jan  MNO  200
2-Jan  WWL  35
3-Feb  ABC  105    
3-Feb  PPP  12
3-Feb  MNO  150
3-Feb  XYZ  25
```

Is this even possible to do using just SQL?

Answer (score 3):

Try such query:

```
INSERT INTO tblHoldings (Date, ID, Quantity)
SELECT '3-Feb', h.ID, h.Quantity + COALESCE(o.Quantity, 0)
FROM tblHoldings h LEFT JOIN tblOrders o ON h.ID = o.ID
WHERE h.Quantity <> o.Quantity
```

The idea is to use `SELECT` statement to get the data that you need, and then use that select to insert the data to holdings table

Comment: would the inner join not mean that PPP wouldn't be inserted for the new date?

Comment: @mHelpMe Yes, it would - thanks for pointing this out. I updated the answer with `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE` function to correctly handle this case

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell if you want WWL in the output or not.  But the basic idea is  `insert . . . select` with a `join`

```
insert into tblHoldings(date, id, quantity)
    select '2015-02-03', id, (h.quantity + o.quantity)
    from tblHoldings h join
         tblOrders o
         on h.id = o.id
    where h.date = '2015-01-02' and
          (h.quantity + o.quantity) <> 0
```

The final condition is only there so WWL is not in the result.  Note that I also used full dates for the comparisons.